# How to find execution time of elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, query-optimization, kibana

I am using elasticsearch to get the fast result from a rails app. I want to know how much time a particular query took to get executed? Is there any tool where I can find and compare execution time so that I can optimize query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'took' attribute in the response object is the execution time in milliseconds. For example:

```
{
  "took" : 17,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to check time took attribute from Kibana UI?